Rect CSS Modules in Camel Case and SCSS Style in Snake - case
I've seen example code where the typescript code in a react application imports CSS as modules. Then you can reference this CSS using Style.cssClassName. However, the scss/css the class name is written using snake case, 'css-class-name'. How is this accomplished? Here is an example.
import Styles from "./Example.module.scss";

export const Example = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Row padded={false} className={Styles.myHeaderRow}>
        <Text size={"medium"} weight={"bold"}>
          <>Sample Content</>
        </Text>
      </Row>
    </>
  );
};

Was trying to get camelCase properties, to conver to snake case CSS classes.

Wouldn't you just do className={Styles['css-class-name']}, unfortunately you'll lose the autocomplete and go to definition. FYI it is kebab-case not snake case.

The kebab-case (or snake-case) should be automatically converted to camelCase when using CSS modules. If this is not the case, you might need some extra configuration in your webpack for the cssloader

@SofiyullahiOlamilekanJ. Yes. It is not.  I’ve done it the way suggested above by using quotes and it works. But using camel case doesn’t.

You can still apply your styling without it being written in camelCase.
import Styles from "./Example.module.scss";

export const Example = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Row padded={false} className={Styles["my-header-row"]}>
        <Text size={"medium"} weight={"bold"}>
          <>Sample Content</>
        </Text>
      </Row>
    </>
  );
};


Yea, but then i have to go through this entire code base and make all those changes.  I was looking for an easy button.

The configuration option you are looking for is exportLocalsConvention see documentation.
You need to add it to your css-loader configuration (as far as I know it doesn't matter whether you use css-loader with webpack or the corresponding css-loader plugin with another popular build tool, the configuration options are identical)
Here is an example:
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        loader: "css-loader",
        options: {
          modules: {
            exportLocalsConvention: "camel-case",
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};

Try out whether 'camel-case' is he right one for you or whether you need one of the other values. I have to admit that the provided descriptions are not clear to me; and it was ages ago that I last had to configure the thing; I can't recall what exactly the right value was for me.
